# Selenium-Unable to Type into TextArea

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter some value in a Text-area using selenium Webdriver and java.
However,sendKeys is not working.
On Using JavaScript,though I am able to enter some value,but as soon as I click save button,I get the error message to enter some value in the Text Area.

Below is the HTML for textarea.

***Below is my selenium code which is not working*** :

```
element=driver.findElement(By.id("primaryClientDemarc"));  
element.clear();  
element.sendKeys("testtextarea");
```

Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: Share Error and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `focus` first on `textarea` using `click()`, try as below :-

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id("primaryClientDemarc"));
element.click();
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("testtextarea");
```

Hope it helps..:)